# Observable does not change when value is set in form

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-forms

I have a form where you can select which location to show.

- It has an Observable (`locations$`) with a list of locations (line 32).
- It has an Observable (`locationCode$`) of the value of the formControl (line 38)
- I create a new Observable (`location$`) that gives the location from the list that has the same code as the selected item (line 41).
- the `location$` observable is then shown on screen (line 16)

When you select an item in the list, the `location$` underneath changes, so that works.

But I want to set the combobox on initial load (line 46) and have that location show up in the view, this I cannot get to work. The form show `null` the first time it's loaded but the combobox has the initial value set.

I see that the `locationCode$` observable changes (see line 43 and console), the `location$` Observable changes too (see line 44 and console), but the view doesn't.

I tried putting the code in OnAfterViewInit() but that didn't help either.

I know I can use a non-observable field and use `this.location$.subscribe(i => this.location = i);` to update that, and that works. But that feels like a hack to me.

See this in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-form-test to see what I mean.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [formGroup]="form">
        Select: <select formControlName="locationCode" name="locationCode">
            <option [value]="null">-- Pick one --</option>
            <option value="1">Show location 1</option>
            <option value="2">Show location 2</option>
            <option value="3">Show location 3</option>
        </select>
        <div>Selected location: {{ location$ | async | json }}</div>
    </div>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  locationCode$: Observable<string>;
  locations$: Observable<{ code: string; name: string; }[]>;
  location$: Observable<{ code: string; name: string; }>;

  constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.builder.group({
      locationCode: this.builder.control(null)
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.locations$ = of([
      { code: '1', name: 'Location 1', city: 'London' },
      { code: '2', name: 'Location 2', city: 'Amsterdam' },
      { code: '3', name: 'Location 3', city: 'Madrid' }
    ]);

    this.locationCode$ = this.form.controls['locationCode'].valueChanges as Observable<string>;
    this.location$ = combineLatest(this.locationCode$, this.locations$)
      .pipe(
        map(([locationCode, locations]) => locations.find(l => l.code === locationCode))
      );
    this.locationCode$.subscribe(i => console.log('locationCode$: ', i))
    this.location$.subscribe(i => console.log('location$    : ', i))
    // I want to set the selected iten here and see the location$ Observable change
    this.form.controls.locationCode.setValue('2');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Angular subscribes to the observable after you called `setValue()`, so it doesn't get any value.

Possible solutions can be:

Use the `startWith` opertator:

`this.form.controls['locationCode'].valueChanges.pipe(startWith('2'))`

Use `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.form.controls.locationCode.setValue('2');
})
```

Now, when Angular subscribes to the value it will get the correct initial value.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have to set both the value of the control (with `.setValue` and the value of the observable (with `.startWith`), which is a bit error-prone.